# Solving Overlapping Images when zooming in Codenameone

Tags: image, codenameone, zoom-sdk

I have an imageviewer with a couple images, When i zoom in the first image and wanna see the right side of the image. The folowing image is overlapping the inzooming image. This is very annoying. Is there a way how i can set the zoom in image on the front.
How can i set the zoomed image always on front.
See picture   https://i.stack.imgur.com/5f5JZ.jpg

My imageviewer is in a container

```
       Image red ;
   red = EncodedImage.create("/HW_Delfzijl_Waddenzee_Oost.jpg");
   Image blue = Image.createImage(500, 500, 0xff0000ff);
   Image red2 = Image.createImage(500, 500, 0xffff0000);   
  Image List1[]= new Image [3];
  
    List1[0] = red;
    List1[1] = blue;
     List1[2] = red2;
    iv = new ImageViewer();
    iv.setWidth(500);
    iv.setHeight(500);
    iv.setImageList(new DefaultListModel<>(List1));
Container1 = BoxLayout.encloseY( Kaarten.AuvHW, AdvSpr,iv,  
    Up,progressbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this with the following code:

```
Form hi = new Form("ImageViewer", BoxLayout.y());
Image red = Image.createImage(2000, 800, 0xffff0000);
Image blue = Image.createImage(2000, 500, 0xff0000ff);
ImageViewer viewer = new ImageViewer();
viewer.setImageList(new DefaultListModel<>(red, blue));
hi.add(BoxLayout.encloseY(viewer, new Label("Dummy")));
hi.show();
```

The problem only happens if I stand on the blue image (the second one) scale it up and then try to move. It doesn't happen when moving from the red image to the blue.

I believe this is due to [this method](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/components/ImageViewer.java#L800-L805) in the `ImagaViewer` code. Since background isn't painted the old image isn't cleaned up. We need to add a condition that disables that while dragging. I think changing the code in that method to this will fix the problem but it's a bit risky and might trigger flickering:

```
protected void paintBackground(Graphics g) {
    // disable background painting for performance when zooming
    if(imageDrawWidth < getWidth() || imageDrawHeight < getHeight() || panPositionX != 0) {
        super.paintBackground(g);
    }
}
```

I would suggest filing an issue so we can consider the options here as this isn't trivial. One partial workaround is to use:

```
viewer.setImageInitialPosition(ImageViewer.IMAGE_FILL);
```

Which minimizes the impact of the issue.

Comment: The difference is that my imageviewer is part of an container.  This is necesary because when i swipe the imageviewer i like to put information in the labels. In the simulator i have a gap between the images but not on the device.

Comment: I updated my sample to give different sizes to the images, made the layout scrollable and nested but still can't reproduce. It looks like you might have a different element. Maybe scrolling. That's interfering with the `ImageViewer`.

Comment: I set your  code in my app with no other elements  then the imageviewer, the label dumy and my sidemenu. Still the images are overlapping when i zoom in with the touch screen. (its about zooming and not scrolling, the picture fits in the viewer) What i noticed is that the overlapping starts at a threshold. Little inzooming has no effect, but whn i further inzoom than they are overlapping.  I dont know which element than is interfering

Comment: i also made i new app only with your code. Still the overlapping is there when i zoom in with touchscreen and go to the right of the image.

Comment: I was able to reproduce. Updated my answer with analysis and workaround.

Comment: hi Shai, 1) the workaround is not working i still have overlapping 2) overlapping appears also when i move van red to blue

Comment: When applying the workaround I saw a very narrow line of overlapping which is probably due to margin or padding. If that's the case setting those to zero should work. As far as I can tell this only happens when there's an aspect ratio difference and the destination image doesn't occupy the entire screen. That was the case in the code I have above and that's the logic behind the overlap.